# Query for date range inside nested arry not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two queries I am running.  Both query for documents inside a date range.  The first example works using this:

```
db.collection('' + site_id + '_page_visits').find({created_at: {"$gte": new Date("" + date + "T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte": new Date("" + date + "T23:59:59.999Z")}}).toArray(...
```

However, the date I need to check on in the second query is nested inside an array inside `call_to_action_responses`, and using the same setup for the date range filter does not work, example:

```
db.collection('' + site_id + '_leads').find({"call_to_action_responses.response_date": {$gte: new Date("" + date + "T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("" + date + "T23:59:59.999Z")}, "call_to_action_responses.page_url": {$not: regex}, "call_to_action_responses.page_url": {$ne: ''} }).toArray(...
```

Using that code it returns all documents matching `$lte` only.  It seems to ignore the `$gte` part of the filter, which works in the first example.

A Sample record looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("XXxXXxxxxxXXxXx"),
  cookie: "xxcXXXXxxx-xxxXXXx-XXXXxx",
  updated_at: ISODate("2016-09-20T01:31:56.677Z"),
  created_at: ISODate("2015-04-22T08:32:34.864Z"),
  call_to_action_responses: [
    {
      response_date: ISODate("2015-04-22T08:32:34.863Z"),
      page_version: "1",
      template_response_path_base: "page_path",
      page_url: "http://www.webiste.com/about",
      page_id: ObjectId("5527d6c40de2c02a0b0000f2"),
      email: "user_email_at@email.com",
      lead_data: {
        phone: "XXXXXXXXX",
        viewed_assets: "This_Asset",
        campaign_medium: "",
        campaign_content: "",
        first_name: "first",
        last_name: "last",
        campaign_source: "",
        campaign_name: "",
        company: "Test Company",
        title: ""
       },
      _id: ObjectId("XXXXxxXXxXXxXXXX"),
      name: "View ",
      target_url: "http://www.webiste.com/about"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  Ir let me know the syntax to this because I cannot seem to get it dialed in.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you show how your collection looks like?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Added an example record

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) Filtering on arrays you either need `$elemMatch` or `$filter`

Comment: `call_to_action_responses` is an array field, you should use `$filter` operator.

Comment: So looking through those answers it looks like they are matching,  I need everything in a range.  I couldn't find an answer there addressing that.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Ok I'll give that a try

Comment: Yaa, you can use `$and` operator, inside `$match`.

Comment: Wait, so I need to use `$and` and `$match`?  Is it possible to just show an example of what the syntax here is, this is what I am struggling to figure out.  Just telling me to use operators doesn;t really help much.

Comment: What is different from this query to what you are trying: https://mongoplayground.net/p/peWBHRc-UKZ

Comment: Not sure seems to work correctly but need to try it with multiple records.  I did not know this page existed, thanks for linking to it

Answer (score 0):

Below query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      call_to_action_responses: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$call_to_action_responses",
          as: "i",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$$i.response_date",
                  new Date("2015-03-23T00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  "$$i.response_date",
                  new Date("2015-06-23T23:59:59.999Z")
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FqEYMh0s6UK)